# how do you find all files and directories without sticky bit?

Tags: permissions, find, sticky-bit

how do you find all files and directories without sticky bit?

I have a bunch of old files that I need to delete so I use: `find . -mtime +3 -a \( -type f -o -type d \)`

But then this find command will still find files with sticky bit permission: `drwxrwxrwt`

I want to make sure my find expressions does not find these files. Or ... should I just be lazy and ignore "operation not permitted" errors (maybe this is the sticky bit's intent/purpose... let's you delete files without worrying about accidently deleting files that you need)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to find stuff with sticky bit set, you need `-perm` parameter, version with slash checks for any of the bits - but we're only going to supply one bit, that is the octal version of sticky bit:

```
find . -perm /1000
```

Now you want to do the reverse, so negate the condition:

```
find . \! -perm /1000
```

And adjusted for your command:

```
find . -mtime +3 -a \( -type f -o -type d \) \! -perm /1000
```